# Details about KiTrap06

Tags: windows, interrupt

I recently started to learn about interrupts, but I feel like I'm missing something important.

I know that when an exception type interrupt occurs I can either let the CPU handle it or I can handle it myself if I use __try/__except.

I know that this interrupt happens when the CPU attempts to execute an invalid op-code. When such an event occurs, the address of the current instruction (so the current eip/rip) is pushed on the stack. The ISR is invoked, does something and then the same instruction is re-executed. 
This got me to think that it somehow tries to skip the invalid op-code or to repair it - otherwise why would the return address be the address of the invalid instruction?

If I compile the following user mode code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("before\n");
    __asm
    {
        UD2
    };
    printf("after\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the application crashes without printing the second message. 
If I put the UD2 in a __try/__except block I can deal with it and the application will no longer crash.

A UD2 instruction in a driver will Blue Screen the system.

So what is KiTrap06 actually doing? Or in this case a crash happens because UD2 is made for testing purposes and in a real case results may differ?

Comment: Big topic, already covered well in a *lot* of literature.  The short version: the trap handler in the kernel reflects this back into the user mode program by throwing an SEH exception.  Exception code 0xc000001c, STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION.  If you have a compiler that lets you write SEH handlers (not GCC) then you can handle this exception by unwinding the stack to get the program to continue and recover from this mishap.  Not generally a great idea, #UD is almost always a sign of a program that ran away due to a corrupted stack.  Possibly intentionally.

Comment: I think I start to understand. So it only raises STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION and the rest rests on the one who writes the code? Let's say that I push on the stack the address of a valid op-code and I jump to the ISR handler (I know this should never be done, but let's just say) will it still raise an exception? All I found about it until now was a small paragraph in an Intel manual.

Comment: Yes.  The trap handler is in the kernel, you can't "jump" to it.  Only the user-mode details are well documented and all you should care about.

Comment: Well, you can write a small driver that will get you the isr and then jump to it. I suppose that this is the only way it could receive a valid op-code and that this case gets us into the undocumented / undefined behavior. Thanks for the answer, it made things clear :)